# Is there a better way to populate multiple dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to populate several DropDownList, and I search the better way to do this, because i've 8 DropDownList to fill. And in my opinion it's not the best way, you have 8 times the same code... It is possible to use a loop ?

```
public partial class MainPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList();
    }

    public void DropDownList()
    { 
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Datas.xml");
        using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
        {
            ds.ReadXml(filePath);
            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "id";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();

            DropDownList2.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "name";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "id";
            DropDownList2.DataBind();

            //Then DropDownList3, 4, 5, 6....8
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XML with my the users:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<users>
  <user>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>User1</name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>User2</name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>User3</name>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>4</id>
    <name>User4</name>
  </user>
</users>
```

Comment: If you have ViewState enabled, make sure that you only load the lists once, by using Page.IsPostback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put them in an array:

```
DropDownList[] ddls = new DropDownList[]{
    DropDownList1, DropDownList2,
    DropDownList3, DropDownList4,
    ...
};
```

And loop through it:

```
foreach (DropDownList ddl in ddls)
{
    ddl.DataSource = ds;
    ddl.DataTextField = "name";
    ddl.DataValueField = "id";
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

A side note though - how could you end up with 8 identical dropdowns on the UI side? Would it be possible to use some kind of repeater for them?

Comment: In my UI, I use severals tabs with JQuery UI and each tab need this DropDownList

Comment: @Julien698, then I would suggest you to consider creating a user control to wrap this all up. This will allow you to avoid code repetition at all

Comment: I don't really know user controls but I'll take a look to this in the aim to optimise my project. Thanks for the advise.